# Jquery selected checkbox counter shows the wrong value on deselect

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I got the selection counter to add/reduce a count based on the selections made. The only problem I am having is when selecting 'All' then deselecting it. When I select it, the counter shows 1 selected which is okay, but when I deselect it, the counter shows '2 selected' which is wrong because nothing is selected! What am I doing wrong?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NwQX7/)**

```
<div id="checkbox_counter"><input type="hidden" name="category[]"  value="0">Select...</div></div>

<label for="all"><input type="checkbox" id="all" class="category_all">All</label>  <br>  
<label for="test1"><input type="checkbox" id="test1" class="all_select">test1</label> <br>
<label for="test2"><input type="checkbox" id="test2" class="all_select">test2</label>
```

jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        var total_checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
        var all_list = $("input.category_all[type=checkbox]:checked").length;   

        if(total_checked > 0){
            if(all_list.length > 0){
                $('#checkbox_counter').replaceWith('<div id="checkbox_counter">All Selected</div>');
            }else{
                $('#checkbox_counter').replaceWith('<div id="checkbox_counter">'+total_checked+' Selected</div>');
            }           
        }else{
            $('#checkbox_counter').replaceWith('<div id="checkbox_counter">Select...</div>');
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass("category_all")) {                     
            $(".all_select").prop("checked", all_list).prop("disabled", all_list);      
        }       
    });
});
```

Comment: it is not selecting the disabled checkboxes that's the reason

Comment: Why are you replacing your counter each time and not just changing the text inside?

Comment: @Ehsan - that's incorrect. OP: You were defining `total_checked` _before_ you decided whether it was the `category_all` checkbox being clicked and setting the `checked` property on the `all_select` checkboxes. Just change the order of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/NwQX7/1/

Comment: also you are getting counter before setting the child checkboxes checked

Comment: ***When I select it, the counter shows 1 selected which is okay*** I thought it should show `2 selected`? because when All is checked, there are actually 2 selected items.

Comment: yes @Joe when i debugged OP code i realized that

Comment: Ah what a stupid mistake on my side! didn't realize that. and @KingKing, you are right. One question though, instead of showing 3 selected, how do I make it say 2 selected when the 'all' is checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your mistake is that you are getting checked checkboxes count before checking the child checkboxes so you just need to change the flow of code like his:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        var all_list = $("input.category_all[type=checkbox]:checked").length;

        if ($(this).hasClass("category_all")) {                     
            $(".all_select").prop("checked", all_list).prop("disabled", all_list);      
        }

        var total_checked = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;


        if(total_checked > 0){
            if(all_list.length > 0){
                $('#checkbox_counter').replaceWith('<div id="checkbox_counter">All Selected</div>');
            }else{
                $('#checkbox_counter').replaceWith('<div id="checkbox_counter">'+total_checked+' Selected</div>');
            }           
        }else{
            $('#checkbox_counter').replaceWith('<div id="checkbox_counter">Select...</div>');
        }



    });
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/HrLLx/2/)

Comment: yeah sorry I didn't think about the 'all' part. Isn't it supposed to say 2 selected rather than 3 when all is selected?